# Почему нельзя прикреплять картинки из сохранённых фотографий в профиле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Могу через `attachment: pic` прикрепить любую картинку, кроме картинок из своего альбома *сохранённых фотографий* в профиле. Профиль открыт, альбом тоже, через приложение вк могу поделиться фотографией. Авторизация через сообщество. Список ссылок всех фотографий у меня в файле.

```
def send(id, text='', pic=''):
    vk_session.method('messages.send',{'chat_id' : id, 'attachment' : pic, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})
```

```
send(id, pic='photo'+user_id+'_'+pic_id)
```

```
vk_session.method('messages.send',{'chat_id' : id, 'attachment' : pic, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})
  File "C:\Users\...\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 668, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: message is empty or invalid
```

Comment: Уверены что используете ссылки на те картинки, которые может увидеть **любой** человек в интернете?

Comment: Уверен, как я писал, альбом открыт и профиль тоже, сам могу без проблем переслать картинку. Вместе с attachment могу прикрепить ещё и text, но в таком случае не выдает ошибки и отправляет только текст